# Safe key access to a Map inside a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to create a class that contains a Map who's keys are type safe. I'm guessing I need to somehow change the generics Key and NewKey (below) into string literals somehow.

```
class MapWrap<Key extends string> {
    map: Map<Key, any>
    constructor() {
        this.map = new Map();
    }

    set<NewKey extends string>(key: NewKey, value: any) {
        (this as MapWrap<Key | NewKey>).map.set(key, value);
        return this as MapWrap<Key | NewKey>;
    }

    get(key: Key) {
        return this.map.get(key)
    }
}

const myMapWrap = new MapWrap();

// This should show an error that "bob" is not a key.
const bob = myMapWrap.set("hello", 1).set("world", 2).get("bob");
```

I tried using 'as const' in various places with not success.

Comment: I don't see how this is useful, but you can do want by declaring you class like `class MapWrap<Key = never>`, so that when you construct a `new MapWrap()`, you get an appropriate empty key type by default.

Comment: ^ That's the right approach here in my opinion; @MattTimmermans do you want to write up an answer for that?